Did I act reasonably by raising following my takeout double?
All vulnerable at matchpoints, right hand opponent opened one club. I doubled (takeout) with the following: ♠KQ75 ♡ T752 ♢ AKJ9 ♣ 3.
Left hand opponent passed, and my new partner bid one spade (forced) with the following: ♠T843 ♡ K86 ♢ 842 ♣ A95.
Right hand opponent passed. I raised to two spades, partly as a mild game try.. Left hand opponent passed, and partner rightly passed, since he did not have the hand I was hoping for.
After the hand was over, he complained, " You needed to have 16 points to raise to two, and you only had 13."
I said, "I put you on a maximum, 6-7 because of the opponent's tepid bidding. (if partner had as few as "5," the (aggressive)opponents would have 22, and I couldn't imagine them remaining silent).
I counted extra over 13 for my club singleton. While I'm glad that he passed with his actual hand, I thought that we had game chances if he had something like ♠T8643 ♡ K8 ♢ 842 ♣ A95. These chances would have been even better if you changed his king of hearts to queen of diamonds (one point less in his hand but four sure diamond tricks).
He made three spades, and got us a top, because other pairs with our cards had 1NT bid and made against them. (I was frankly surprised that our opponents stayed silent with "20," and my 2 spade bid was partly pre-emptive against left hand opponent. Afterward one of the opponents defended me by saying, "I don't see what you were complaining about. You made an overtrick over two spades, and it seems like Tom had a point when he thought you could make game with the right distribution."
I believe that it was Marty Bergen who said something like, "you can try for x (e.g. game) if partner's maximum will allow you to make it, to give partner a chance to bid it." Is that principle operative here and if so, do these hands qualify?

You have a very good 13 for a takeout double of 1♣ - 4-4 in the majors, singleton club, all cards "working", even the ten of hearts.
Traditional expectation is "double with an opening hand counted as dummy points."  With that view, your hand is closer to 16 than 13.
Can you make game opposite a maximum?  Sure - Partner's hand isn't even close to a maximum, and the ♣A isn't pulling its full weight.  Shortness in hearts, with the trump A and the diamond queen, likely leads to game right there.  But that's a magic hand.  They exist, and the "perfect minimum" (in this case, the "perfect minimum maximum") theory applies.
But let's look at the alternative: partner has ♠Jxx ♥Qx ♦ xxx ♣xxxxx.  I've even given him a three-count, could even be 4 (♥K instead of the Q) could be more with wasted club quacks.  That's an equal "magic hand" to the other one, just the wrong kind of magic.  You might make only 5 tricks; and you almost certainly won't make 8.  Sure, it's much more likely you have a 4-4 major fit than if partner responded 1♥ because he bypassed both red suits, but in "White Queen land" (as opposed to "magical Christmas land" - same weather, different magic), you could be facing this.  The opponents likely can't make any game; -200 is still the "matchpoint death score", and you could easily get there undoubled.
Should you look for game?  I wouldn't do it, but I don't think it's Wrong.  I think it's dead minimum, though - you're looking for a well-fitting 19-21 point game, and you can't really ask what you really want to know - "how many heart losers do we have, pd?"  But if partner plays the spots off the cards on the regular, and/or you're playing the pair you can pretty much guarantee will give away a trick in defence (and won't double you, even in 3), well then.
Of course, one of the ways expert declarers win at matchpoints is that 1♠+3 beats all the 1♠+2s exactly as much as 4♠= does, while not losing to them when even they can only make 9 tricks.  Remember your goal at matchpoints is not to get the best score possible, it's to get a better score than the other pairs.
Now all of this is assuming you're getting a free run at it, and will be allowed to play 1♠.  I don't believe that for a minute, but it could happen (and I'd probably hate it if it does, because the trumps are 4-1 at best).  You can pass this, and come back in with 2, in a way that if they decide they want to compete against "2 of a fit", you won't want to come back in at the three level.
Having said all of that, declarer's comment when dummy came down was bad. Giving the defenders hope during the play is a fast track to their best defence (and, again, that overtrick might make all the difference!)  That's a natural reaction we all do, sure, but a habit it's best to break.
"I expected a little more for the raise, partner, I might have gone on with a better hand and have no play" after the play (better yet, away from the table after the round) is just explaining to you what he expects to see and counts on for his decisionmaking.  And frankly, the answer I keep harping on, here and elsewhere, is "doing what partner expects is better than being 'right'" - and if partner wants 16 Miltons for this raise, to judge correctly, then pass him next time with 15.  But the right time for this discussion is when the opponents aren't there to "support you", and definitely not when the opponents are still concentrating on taking tricks.

It was partly a matter of "playing the players." We got a top on the board because other pairs with our opponents' cards bid and made 1NT. Our opponents were aggressive, and I wanted to head off a competing bid by LHO. If my partner had as few as 5 points, opponents would have had 22, and it is INconceivable that they would have refrained from bidding--in fact, I was surprised that they kept quiet with "20" when all their counterparts bid 1NT. I put opponents on 18-20, and did not rule out the possibility that partner had "bid shy" by not raising with 8 points, perhaps ♠Axx ♥KJ ♦ xxx ♣xxxxx.

Your opponents are never playing 1NT. You're always going to bid 2♠ eventually, right? Do you think they're making 2NT when you know what to lead?  I like AWoo's ideas, but I'd want to have it very clear, in advance that we're playing that.  But you will get another chance.

Frankly, I hate the admittedly still standard agreement that a raise to 2 here promises extra strength.  I think a raise to 2 here should just promise 4 card support.  Good opponents will never let you play in a fit at the 1 level, and keeping the opponents from finding a fit at the 2 level and then finding 3 level bid over your 2 level contract is just that important.  -100 is better than -110 (if you go down in 2S and they make 3C or 3D), and +110 is better than +100 (if you make 2S and they go down in 3C or 3D).
There is a downside, which is that you've got fewer ranges of invitational bids, and that means you'll make the wrong decision about playing game more often.  Especially at matchpoints, that's a cost I'm willing to play in order to keep opponents from getting competitive bidding correct more often.
However, I do sometimes play treatments that I hate just to keep partner happy, and partner sometimes does the same for me.
